# Local resources not loading on iOS 9.3.1 physical devices

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

As the title says, none of my local resources are loading on iOS 9.3.1 physical devices (neither images in an `ImageView`, neither translations, neither other files via `Ti.Filesystem.getFile()`). The following code results in a blank, white image (even though the image definitely exists on the filesystem):

```
Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width  : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    image  : '/images/bg01.jpg'
});
```

The above code runs and displays correctly on all combinations of the iOS simulator, and on a physical 7.1 iOS device (as well as all Android devices and emulators). Unfortunately I don't have access to a physical 9.3.1 device so I cannot see the logs.

This is using Titanium SDK 5.2.2GA.

Comment: Check that the file name and folder name are proper with case-convention. iOS device is case-sensitive. Also as mentioned by Prashant, convert from JPG to PNG and check.

Comment: How did you build to device? Directly from the AppC/Ti CLI or Studio or via Xcode. In the last case, there's a known issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using png files in case you are using only jpg files and share a snapshot of your directory layout so that we can confirm nothing wrong with the directory or file names ?

But as you have also said that it is working on all simulators, so I assume that it is working on iOS 9.x versions as well, in this case you really need to test your app on physical device.

Apart from this, I can test your code on my iPhone 9.3.1 as I usually work on 9.3.1 and never faced such odd issue, so either provide us full/some code which is having issues or test it on real device.

It might be an issue with the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the case is right.  If I recall correctly the simulators are not case-sensitive but the physical devices are?

I have ran into this issue using xCode.  For some reason images are left our as well as the Localizable.strings files.  I have yet to figure out a way around this and I have to manually add them to the xCode project.

See this for help [TIMOB-19818](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19818).  Christopher.fox comment is the one that lead me to solving my issue.